# golang: Omit name of struct in xml.Marshal

Tags: xml, go

Trying to get a particular output for XML:

```
<RESPONSE>
    <DELIMITER value="09"></DELIMITER>
    <COLUMNS>Id FirstName   LastName    Company Initials</COLUMNS>
     <DATA>87734    Some Guy    Keller Williams Realty Empire   </DATA>
     <DATA>87739    Another Guy Level Group, Inc.   </DATA>
     <DATA>87741    Some Gal    Kian Realty NYC, LLC    </DATA>
</RESPONSE>
```

instead I am getting:

```
<RESPONSE>
 <compactData>
        <DELIMITER value="09"></DELIMITER>
        <COLUMNS>Id FirstName   LastName    Company Initials</COLUMNS>
        <DATA>87734 Some Guy    Keller Williams Realty Empire   </DATA>
        <DATA>87739 Another Guy Level Group, Inc.   </DATA>
        <DATA>87741 Some Gal    Kian Realty NYC, LLC    </DATA>
 </compactData>
</RESPONSE>
```

I am trying not to output the <compactData> tag at all. (everything else is a-ok)

my struct that I am marshal-ing looks like this:

```
type delimiter struct {
    Value string `xml:"value,attr"`
}

type innerData struct {
    Data string `xml:",innerxml"`
}

type compactData struct {
    Delimiter delimiter    `xml:"DELIMITER"`
    Columns   *innerData   `xml:"COLUMNS"`
    Records   []*innerData `xml:"DATA"`
}
```

I have tried putting in

```
XMLName   xml.Name
```

or

```
XMLName   xml.Name `xml:""`
```

to no avail- the xml.MarshalIndent just says 'yeah that looks like crap taking the struct name instead'.

I feel as though I just may need to reorganize the struct a bit, but I am stumped as to the magic structure needed.

Thanks!

Edit: the <RESPONSE> tag is added as the http.reponse is sent, after this formatting is done, trying to keep this signature the same as JSON and XML encoding...

like so:

```
func createResponse(obj interface{}, format string) (*Response, error) {
    var data []byte

    var f func(interface{}, string, string) ([]byte, error)

    switch format {
    case FORMAT_JSON:
        f = json.MarshalIndent
    case FORMAT_COMPACT:
        f = compact.MarshalIndent
    default:
        f = xml.MarshalIndent
    }
    data, err := f(obj, " ", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil, err
    }
    return &Response{Data: string(data)}, nil

}
```

Comment: Where does the `RESPONSE` come from? Is that another type that contains `compactData`? Or?

Comment: the RESPONSE tag is wrapped around the http response at the very end, the data can be formatted in different ways, so I am hoping to have the same 

    func Marshal(obj interface{}) ([]byte, error)

signature for the stuff I am doing here, then wrap it well after the data is formatted as http.response is sent out. But good eye.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `RESPONSE` is another `struct` you could embed `compactData` in it and let `encoding/xml` do what you want.

```
type RESPONSE struct {
    compactData
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hN1hDY7pnV

**Update**:
Actually you can do what you want, if I understood you correctly, by implementing the `xml.Marshaler` interface. E.g. something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/Uwm0pP1pWh.

Comment: In this case, the response tag gets wrapped around the results of this func call afterwards, and I have other data generators that are treated similarly (i.e. json, plain-old xml), so would like to avoid this, but based on how I worded the question this is a good catch.

Comment: @Slabgorb in that case what about the example in the update, implementing `xml.Marshaler`, does that get closer to what you want to achieve?

Comment: excellent thank you! Got stuck on the cuteness of the tags - been working with HUGE structs where that would be super annoying, but for this that works perfectly.